# Octopus Deploy: No package for the action 'xxxxxx' and machine 'Machine-Name' was acquired

Tags: deployment, teamcity, web-deployment, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

I am starting to delve into [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/) and setting up my first deployment but I've ran into a bit of a snag. I have tried to be as specific as possible in lieu of finding someone who has experienced this same problem more recently. "This is not a new problem. See -*reseach*"

**The setup**

Versions:

1. TeamCity 10.0.4
2. Octopus Deploy 3.10.1

My continuous integration stack is comprised of TFS, TeamCity and now Octopus. My deployment process:

1. TeamCity runs the .NET application build. (Scripts, tests, etc..)
2. [TeamCity Octopus plugin](https://octopus.com/downloads) successfully creates the versioned Nuget packages.
3. A TeamCity build step using "*OctopusDeploy: Push packages*" pushes the packages to the octopus server.
4. In Octopus an external feed was added an tested called "*Octopus Local Packages*" pointing to the default internal octopus package directory: *C:\Octopus\Packages*.
5. An octopus project was created with a single step using the "*Deploy an IIS Web Site*" template, where the package section is setup like this:
   [image]

**The problem**

[image]

**Research**

This has happened in the past on versions prior to 3.0.7 where it was fixed. [Link to bug thread 1](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/1782).

Then it started happening again at some point prior to version 3.4.15 where it was fixed. [Link to bug thread 2](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/48224-no-package-for-the-action-and-machine-was-acquired).

---

Any help, fix, or workaround will be greatly appropriated. If there is a detail that I'm missing I will be more than happy to clarify.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your deployment process, please? (tag me in a comment when done so I get a notification `:-)`)

Comment: @gvee, Thanks for the response. I have added an answer with a series of mistakes that I made, and what I did to fix them. This was certainly a head scratcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

This may very well be a rookie mistake when it comes to Octopus. The error shown in the question is in fact a result of the deployment package not being found. The following are findings through documentation and trial an error:

1. **Octopus Server (built in)** is a push feed only. Meaning that packages can be uploaded to this feed but not consumed.
2. To consume Octopus' server local packages, namely the packages previously pushed to **Octopus Server (built in)** from say *TeamCity*, you have to serve those packages yourself.
3. You can server those packages through Octopus by creating an external feed that points to the server's package default path: `C:\Octopus\Packages`

**Most Importanly, and the fix to the error!**

4. When changes are made to a deployment process step, **a new release MUST BE created**. Simply redeploying the previous release will try to redeploy with the previous step settings saved in a snapshot and not with the new step settings. This may come a a surprise to **TeamCity** users like myself based on TeamCity's behaviour.